# Keyboard and Mouse work in ubuntu and bios but not in windows

Tags: multi-boot, partitioning, mouse

OK, I have read a bunch of posts, and tried many fixes, but still having problems.

Background:
pc has a 250gg ssd samsung 840 evo. this was in 2 partitions.
1 partition was being used for windows 7. A torrent dl exploded it with spyware. I took some documents I wanted to back up and put them into the partition drive using and ubuntu bootable usb.

This is the first time I have ever tried linux. I then began trial by error partition and restructuring the whole hard drive. What I have now is this

Partition 2 'Windows' - 105 GB NTFS

Partition 3 'Swap' - 16 GB Swap (has star in bottom right corner)

Partition 4 'Extended partition' - 129 GB

- Sub partition(no sure what it's called) under Partition 4 are both 5 and 6

Partition 5 'Filesystem' - 25 GB ext4

Partition 6 'Filesystem' - 104 GB ext4

I know its a lot of information but I want to make it as easy as possible for everyone. Bear with me!

I installed ubuntu onto one of the drives -> formated the windows drive and installed windows. But the mouse and keyboard would not work.

They work in both ubuntu and bios. They did INTERMITTENTLY on windows when going between safe mode and normal. At one point I was able to install the B85M-E asus motherboard support dvd and installed all the drivers. After one of the several restarts that were required to install drivers, both a wireless keyboard and mouse and a direct USB mouse do not work on windows at any time.

I have checked all options in BIOS. I tried to reinstall drivers and reformat windows but no mouse or keyboard makes this impossible.

ANY tips, ANY questions, ANY help, is GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks,
Anthony F

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: This ^ - you will more likely get help on SuperUser. You can flag your post for moderator attention and they will migrate it for you...

Comment: sorry for the incorrect use of this forum! will try using superuser

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stands out as odd really looking at the information you provided. It seems to be a Windows problem not really anything to do with Ubuntu. You could try changing your USB to Legacy mode within your BIOS or just jump on the Windows 10 train xD.

Hope this was of some assistance.

Comment: thanks for the help! I'm still having trouble trying to install steam for example onto Ubuntu but I guess that's part of the learning curve.